# How to plot day into row using GridView in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing some development a table where I can plot data into GridView. It was a 12 by 31 days table which is every price need to plot the data into respected day row and column. Example for January, there need to plot on the row for January and so on. The sample data below are the exact data I only need the Price that need to plot on the row. Sample view.

```
      1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | and so on to 31
January  100|100|100|100|100|100|100|100|100|100 | and so on to 31

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] months = new string[]
            {
                "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
            };

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Projects\TestSample\TestSample\RenderJsonToView\prices.json"))
            {
                string jsonObject = reader.ReadToEnd();

                var prices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ComparePrice>>(jsonObject);

                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

                    dataTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[32]
                    {
                        new DataColumn("Months", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day1", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day2", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day3", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day4", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day5", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day6", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day7", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day8", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day9", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day10",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day11",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day12",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day13",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day14",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day15",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day16",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day17",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day18",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day19",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day20",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day21",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day22",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day23",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day24",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day25",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day26",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day27",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day28",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day29",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day30",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Day31",typeof(string))
                    });

                    for (int i = 0; i < prices.Count; i++)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
                        {
                            dataRow["Day1"] = prices[i].Prices[0].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day2"] = prices[i].Prices[1].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day3"] = prices[i].Prices[2].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day4"] = prices[i].Prices[3].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day5"] = prices[i].Prices[4].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day6"] = prices[i].Prices[5].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day7"] = prices[i].Prices[6].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day8"] = prices[i].Prices[7].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day9"] = prices[i].Prices[8].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day10"] = prices[i].Prices[9].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day11"] = prices[i].Prices[10].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day12"] = prices[i].Prices[11].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day13"] = prices[i].Prices[12].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day14"] = prices[i].Prices[13].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day15"] = prices[i].Prices[14].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day16"] = prices[i].Prices[15].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day17"] = prices[i].Prices[16].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day18"] = prices[i].Prices[17].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day19"] = prices[i].Prices[18].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day20"] = prices[i].Prices[19].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day21"] = prices[i].Prices[21].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day22"] = prices[i].Prices[22].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day23"] = prices[i].Prices[23].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day24"] = prices[i].Prices[24].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day25"] = prices[i].Prices[25].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day26"] = prices[i].Prices[26].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day27"] = prices[i].Prices[27].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day28"] = prices[i].Prices[28].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day29"] = prices[i].Prices[29].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day30"] = prices[i].Prices[30].ToString();
                            dataRow["Day31"] = prices[i].Prices[31].ToString();
                        }

                        foreach (var price in prices[i].Prices)
                        {
                            dataTable.Rows.Add(months[i], price);
                        }
                    }

                    GridViewTest.DataSource = dataTable;
                    GridViewTest.DataBind();
                }

            }
        }
```

Data JSON

```
[
  {
    "Month": 1,
    "Prices": [
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-02T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-03T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-04T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-05T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-06T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-07T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-08T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-09T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-10T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-11T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-12T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-13T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-14T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-15T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-16T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-17T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-18T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-19T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-20T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-21T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-22T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-23T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-24T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-25T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-26T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-27T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 2,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-28T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 1,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-29T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 1,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-30T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      },
      {
        "RoomsAllocated": 2,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "MinimumStay": 1,
        "Inclusion": "breakfast and lunch",
        "Date": "2018-01-31T00:00:00",
        "RoomsAllocatedDirty": true,
        "PriceDirty": true,
        "StopSellDirty": true,
        "MinimumStayDirty": true,
        "InclusionDirty": true
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For years I have created a system for a hotel with the website and I have had a similar situation, maybe you get something, the difference is that just as you have room prices in a JSON file, I put it in a table, finally there were more tables, and the price per room was calculated by the factors of season, days in advance, the type of room, and if there was a some holidas in between. where I have the **var Q**, you can put your JSON query This is a code:

```
 public DataTable DoGrid()
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;
        dt.Columns.Add("No", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Occupation", typeof(string));
        for(day = CalFrom.Date; day <= CalTo; day = day.AddDays(1))
        {
            var Q = db.Reservas.Where(c => c.CheckIn <= day && c.CheckOut > day && c.Cancelado == false);
            string MyMonth = dtfi.GetMonthName(day.Month).ToString();
            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["No"] = dt.Rows.Count + 1;
            row["Year"] = day.Year.ToString();
            row["Month"] = MyMonth;
            row["Date"] = day.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            row["Occupation"] = Q.Count();
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return dt;
    }

    public DateTime day { get; set; }

    public DateTime CalFrom
    {
        get
        {
            return DpFrom.Value.Value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime CalTo
    {
        get
        {
            return DpTo.Value.Value;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = DoGrid();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And this is result of the code
[image: Data Table Example]